# Set QFIle save directory

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code which creates a file and writes to it.

```
QFile file(saveFilename);
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QTextStream out(&file);

out << name + " - " + size + "\n";

file.close();
```

Where will this file be saved?
I have a variable called `QString saveFileDirectory` which I want the file to be saved in.

Any tips on how to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: The file named `saveFilename` will be saved in the current working directory unless you provide a file path too.

Comment: And how do I attach a file path? That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: `saveFilename = saveFileDirectory + '/' + saveFilename; QFile file(saveFilename);`

Comment: Ahh so you attach the directory/path to the filename itself. That's what I was after. Put it as an answer @vahancho so I can green tick it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide only a file name, file will be saved in the current working directory. In order to save it into a particular directory you have to provide the full file path to the `QFile` object. For example:

```
QString fileName;
QString directoryName;
QString filePath = directoryName + '/' + fileName;
QFile file(filePath);
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    // Write the file content.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do like the following:**

```
QFile file("c://directoryName/outfile.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream out(&file);
out << "This is an example of data\n";

// optional, as QFile destructor will already do it:
file.close();
```

Or

Also you can use `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName` to save the file data by using save Dialog.

Comment: What does the QIODevice::Text achieve?

Comment: @Luke: `QIODevice::Text`: When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'. When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32.